# Border radius between two blocks

Tags: css

How I can create border like in this demo [image]

I try create something like this but can't find way how to change border between two block the same like in demo.
My example here:

```css
.title {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F9B700;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 7px 5px;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  width: 40%;
}

.right {
  width: 60%;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="title">Création de site e-commerce à Nantes</div>
  </div><div class="right"></div>
  <div class="content">Doter votre commerce en ligne de solutions performantes est un impératif pour vous démarquer de vos concurrents. Cela passe par le déploiement des outils adéquats pour le fonctionnement de votre site web</div>
</div>
```

Comment: which other div needs the border as you want it? the one with the right class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use pseudo element like this:

```css
.title {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F9B700;
  width:40%;
  padding: 7px 5px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top:none;
  border-right:none;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position:relative;
}
.content:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
  left:9px;
  width:42%;
  height:30px;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.content:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  height:calc(100% + 38px);
  right:0;
  width:calc(58% - 10px);
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-wrapper">
  <div class="title">Création de site e-commerce à Nantes</div>
  <div class="content">Doter votre commerce en ligne de solutions performantes est un impératif pour vous démarquer de vos concurrents. Cela passe par le déploiement des outils adéquats pour le fonctionnement de votre site web</div>
</div>
```